# Drawing a rectangle on a video in C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, emgucv

Hi I want to **draw** a **rectangle** on a **video** stream(web cam video or loaded saved video) that I have streaming on a picture box. This is a C# application and I am using EmguCV 2.1.0.0. I have been successful in displaying the video stream on the picturebox in the form.

Can I use Emgucv to draw on the video or should I use something else ? Can I use Dshownet or something like that ?

*Thanks for taking the time to read this.*

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is update the picture box on some callback you receive with every frame:

```
Bitmap bm = ...;    
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
{
    gr.DrawRectangle(somePoint, someRectangle);
}

pictureBox.Image = bm;
```

The downside of this method is the image won't refresh itself unless another frame comes along, so you may have to have other methods to invoke a draw action.  You can also use gr.DrawString and any other methods in the Graphics class to draw to the bitmap.

Comment: thks for the reply. I am particularly  interested in drawing using a mouse. I am sorri I didnt mention that